# Your friend emails you a passage:

Tags: steganography

> I received an email from your friend:
>
> > From: JK123@fmail.com
> >
> > To: hehehaha@fmail.com
> >
> > Title: A passage
> >
> > Body:
> >
> > Today, i went to the pharmacy. I asked the staff, "How much is
> >
> > a bottle of alcohol? I has not much at home." The staff replied,
> >
> > "$10 per 100mL, not many money needed." So I decided to buy
> >
> > 2L of alohol.
> >
> > After I went back home, Jeff called me, "Does you have any
> >
> > alcohol? I want some." I replied, "Your have already gotten
> >
> > 1L of alcohol from me! I don't wan to give you any more alcohol!
> >
> > I have only same alcohol left at home after giving you the 1L!"
>
> I was puzzled. Could anyone help me to find out why my friend sent me the email?

---

Hint 1:

> Look at the tag below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, detect the words in the passage that need to be edited in order for the passage to make sense:

> Today, **i** to  went to the pharmacy. I asked the staff, "How much is
>
> a bottle of alcohol? I **has** not much at home." The staff replied,
>
> "$10 per 100mL, not **many** money needed." So I decided to buy
>
> 2L of **alohol**.
>
> After I went back home, Jeff called me, "**Does** you have any
>
> alcohol? I want some." I replied, "**Your** have already gotten
>
> 1L of alcohol from me! I don't **wan** to give you any more alcohol!
>
> I have only **same** alcohol left at home after giving you the 1L!"

Then, edit the words:

> Today, **I** went to the pharmacy. I asked the staff, "How much is
>
> a bottle of alcohol? I **have** not much at home." The staff replied,
>
> "$10 per 100mL, not **much** money needed." So I decided to buy
>
> 2L of **alcohol**.
>
> After I went back home, Jeff called me, "**Do** you have any
>
> alcohol? I want some." I replied, "**You** have already gotten
>
> 1L of alcohol from me! I don't **want** to give you any more alcohol!
>
> I have only **some** alcohol left at home after giving you the 1L!"

Put the words into a list, and you have the answer:

> I
> Have
> Much
> Alcohol
> Do
> You
> Want
> Some

Comment: Don't forget the 'your' between your fourth and fifth words! :) You might also consider the lower-case 'i' in the first line...

Comment: This is the correct answer! Checkmark incoming!